# Do I have to submit transcripts from school I transferred out of for grad application?

Tags: graduate-admissions, transcript-of-records

Every grad school requires to submit transcripts from all undergrad and grad instatutions applicant attended including studying abroad.

Personally I am confused with one case. I entered first University just after the high school, but a year after I dropped it and entered another University (a branch of a well-known University that had been opened that very year). The main reason was that the latter University had a program with more advanced and fundamental courses in math and CS and with a researh component as a part of curriculum, and it generally better fit my interests and desires (another reasons were e.g. better professors, better ranking).

I feel that this episode of my life is worth mentioning in my SoP (I preferred to waste a year because I wanted to dedicate my life to science and therefore get better training for this goal). However I'm not sure if I had to get transcripts from that first University even if I just studied there for a year and wasn't satisfied with it's level of education.

Can anyone answer if I am obligated to get and submit this document?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a graduate school requires transcripts from all your undergraduate institutions, then I would understand that to include the university you attended for just a year.  Under the circumstances you describe, the content of that transcript should not have much effect on the admission decision (or on fellowship offers), but omitting it seems risky because it could get your application rejected (or ignored) on a technicality.

Comment: Worse still: you can be admitted, and then have the offer of admission rescinded if it comes to light you had an earlier transcript which you did not submit.

Comment: Was a one-month summer program in another university (where I took one course) included in that category?

Comment: @JohnZHANG If the course was a regular university course (listed in the university's course catalog), then you should definitely include it. If it was something else that existed just for this particular summer program, then the situation is less clear (to me); I'd be inclined to include it anyway, but I'm reluctant to say that you definitely need to include it.

Comment: @AndreasBlass It's a regular university course. But in most online application system, I can only find place to fill in the information of those institutions where I have got a degree. And since I have already transferred the credit back (the course is listed in the transcript issued by my home university with a Pass), do you think I should apply for a transcript for that particular course from that university during application?

Comment: As long as the course is listed in your application, as transferred credit at your home university, I think it should be OK.  But my opinion isn't what counts; the important opinion is that of the admissions folks at the place(s) you're applying to.